# Using jQuery to replace an input with an output from an API

Tags: jquery, api, http, dynamic, replace

I've a text box and a submit button. When the form is submitted (enter pressed or button clicked), I'd like the browser to remain on the current page and not reload anything.

I'd like to take the input from the text field, use this data to contact an HTTP GET API, then return the output from the API back into the input text box, and highlight the output so that it can be copied to clipboard.

I'm new to jQuery, so if anyone's willing to write this hopefully small snippet of code, it'd be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code says:

- When the form submits...
- don't do the default thing (submitting the form)...
- send a GET request to the specified server with a certain value, then when it completes run a function that...
- puts the data into the input and...
- selects the text in the input.

You'll need to change your URL, the `mystring` to whatever the server is expecting as a paramater, and if you have multiple forms or inputs, you'll need to specify ids or classes (e.g. `form#myid` or `form.myclass`). Other than that this should work.

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get("/url/from/get/api", {mystring: $('input').val()}, function(data, status) {
        $('input').val(data);
        $('input').select()
    });
    return false;
})
```

Read more at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you. You can't ajax cross domain.

```
$(function(){
    $('#idOfForm').on('submit', function(e){
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'curl.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            datatype: 'post',
            success: function(data){
                //do something with returned data
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

curl.php:

```
$url = 'http://apiurl.com'; 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch ,CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
$err = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
echo $contents ? $contents : $err;
```

Comment: `e = e || window.event;` - what's this for?

Comment: to support for older internet explorer browsers

Comment: Basically what it's saying is if `e` is `undefined` then use `window.event` instead.

Comment: I **do know** javascript syntax, and my question was: **why** do you need that?

Comment: Sorry it's not for old IE as i thought it's for Netscape http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_access.html

Comment: oh, I didn't even know it still alive :-S

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#your_button_id').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); //to stay on same page
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'your_url',
    data: $('#form_id').serialize(),
    success: function(response){
        //On success you will have responce from server
        //Do all yo need with buttons and texts
    }
  });
});
```